# Write int to output stream and unbound value

Tags: sockets, ocaml

I am trying to output integers to

```
Unix.out_channel_of_descr
```

I am currently using `output_string` function and I am wondering, are there any functions like `output_int` ?. Furthermore, when I try to use a function called `write`, it shows me an error called `unbound value write`, I assume I need to import a module for this how do you solve this issue?.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to write to the output? Do you want to write a series of characters that represent the integer, or do you want to write the integer itself (a binary value)? For the former, the easiest is probably: `output_string (string_of_int x)`. (This might be what you're doing now.) For the latter there is `output_binary_int`.

If you have complex values that you want to send through a byte stream, you might look at the [`Marshal`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html) module.

It's not clear which function called `write` you're looking for. There is a `write` function in the `Unix` module. So maybe `Unix.write` is what you want?

Unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise, it might be best to use either Unix I/O or native OCaml I/O. You seem to be using a mixture of the two. You might have some buffering problems if you direct both kinds of output to the same place.